# ttk combobox selection synchronize the state of entry

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I would like to realize a special case, when i select the value in combobox, the entry state changes correspondingly, e.g. when i select 1 in levels, the entry of level-1 is active, while the entry of level-2 is disabled, can anyone give me some suggestion. when i select 2 in levels, both of the state of entry are enabled.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk



class MainGui(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        label_1 = tk.Label(self,
                  text = "Levels:",
                  anchor = 'w')
        label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        ComboBox1 = ttk.Combobox(self, width = 10, state = 'readonly')
        ComboBox1["values"] = ("1", "2")
        ComboBox1.current(0)
        ComboBox1.grid(row=0, column=1)

        label1 = tk.Label(self,
                  text = "Level-1:",
                  anchor = 'w')
        label1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        entry1 = tk.Entry(self,
                      width = 10,
                      )
        entry1.grid(row=1, column=1)

        label2 = tk.Label(self,
                  text = "Level-2:",
                  anchor = 'w')
        label2.grid(row=2, column=0)

        entry2 = tk.Entry(self,
                      width = 10,
                      )
        entry2.grid(row=2, column=1)


def main():

    # gui
    root = MainGui()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the virtual event `<<ComboboxSelected>>` on `ComboBox1` and update the state of `Entry2` in the event callback which will be executed whenever the selection of `ComboBox1` is changed.  But you need to change `ComboBox1` and `entry2` to instance variables in order to access them inside the event callback:

```
def create_widgets(self):
    ...
    # changed ComboBox1 to instance variable self.ComboBox1
    self.ComboBox1 = ttk.Combobox(self, width = 10, state = 'readonly')
    self.ComboBox1["values"] = ("1", "2")
    self.ComboBox1.current(0)
    self.ComboBox1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    self.ComboBox1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.on_select)
    ...
    # changed entry2 to instance variable self.entry2
    self.entry2 = tk.Entry(self,
                          width = 10,
                          state = "disabled"  # initially disabled
                          )
    self.entry2.grid(row=2, column=1)

def on_select(self, event=None):
    # set state of entry2 based on selected value
    self.entry2.config(state="normal" if self.ComboBox1.get()=="2" else "disabled")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution (sample):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Entry, Frame
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox


entry_list = []


def activate_entries(event=None):
    to = int(combobox.get())
    for entry in entry_list[:to]:
        entry.config(state='normal')
    for entry in entry_list[to:]:
        entry.config(state='disabled')


root = Tk()

values = []
for i in range(5):
    (frame := Frame(root)).grid(row=i + 1, column=0)
    Label(frame, text=f'Level-{i + 1}').pack()
    (e := Entry(frame, state='disabled' if i != 0 else 'normal',
                disabledbackground='grey80')).pack()
    entry_list.append(e)
    values.append(i + 1)

combobox = Combobox(root, values=values, state='readonly')
combobox.current(0)
combobox.grid(row=0, column=0)

combobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', activate_entries)

root.mainloop()
```

The main part here is the `activate_entries()` function, it simply gets the value from combobox and uses a list of the entries to set their state based on their index in the list which is given by the combobox. (Also some parts require a Python version of 3.8 or higher, can be adjusted for older versions too), also note the `<<ComboboxSelected>>` event that calls the `activate_entries()` function when user selects something from the combobox.

EDIT: added `disabledbackground='grey80'` to visually indicate that the entry is disabled

EDIT2: you can obviously set the range to two which will create two entries, their reference is saved in the `entry_list` so you can access them through that list to get their value for example